# Как можно определить с какой стороны следующая плитка в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть ли способ определить заранее с какой сторони плитка от плеера?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Структура prefabs:***

1:

```
 LeftTile
        Tile
            LeftAttachPoint
            TopAttachPoint
```

2:

```
 TopTile
        Tile
            LeftAttachPoint
            TopAttachPoint
```

***Script:***

```
public class TileManager : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject [] prefabs;
public GameObject currentTile;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            SpawnTile();
        }       
    }

    void SpawnTile()
    {
        int RandomIndex = Random.Range(0,2);
        currentTile = (GameObject) Instantiate(prefabs[RandomIndex],currentTile.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(RandomIndex).position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если координаты по Y центра плитки больше координат игрока, то плитка сверху, если меньше, то снизу. Если координаты плитки по Х больше координат X игрока, то плитка справа, если меньше, то слева.

Comment: перемещение по координатам. `Влево (-X)`, `прямо (Z)`.то есть, если с левой стороны `Tile Center (-X) < Player Center (X)`
а прямо, `Tile Center (-Z) < Player Center (-Z)` верно?

Comment: По идее да, однако поэксперементируйте и проверьте, это то, что вам нужно или нет

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, ты имеешь, скрипт прикрепленный к игроку, который устанавливает его позицию (grid position), здесь примерно похожая ситуация [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294664/for-loop-is-executed-always-just-once). Только здесь проверка на плитки по диагонали, для твоего же игрока плитка с координатами (2,1) будет являться Tile Forward, а Tile Left - (1,0) соответственно. Здесь есть одна загвоздка, тайлы имеют собственные позиции в глобальной (мнимой) сетке и создан лист, в который занесены значения существующих позиций тайлов. Таким образом проверка включает в себя лишь условие на содержание в листе пойнта, который хочешь проверить на то, справа он или спереди от игрока, и, присваивание локальному массиву, состоящему из двух ячеек, проверяемые позиции (для дальнейшей работы с ними).
Пример скриптов:

PlayerScript:

```
public class PlayerScript: MonoBehaviour{
public Point GridPosition { get; set; }

public void SetGridPosition(Point gridPos){
    this.GridPosition = gridPos; //Этот метод нужен для установки новой позиции игрока при перемещении на тайл с такой-то позицией.
}
}
```

TileScript

При создании клонов тайлов из префаба в иерархии, мы можем им присвоить свои позиции относительно расположения в мнимой сетке и сделать ссылки на объекты путём добавления листа тайлов:

```
public class TileScript: MonoBehaviour{
public Point GridPosition { get; set; }

public void SetTileGridPosition (Point gridPos, GameObject Tile, Vector3 newTilePos){
    this.GridPosition = gridPos;
    Tile.transform.position = newTilePos;
    GameManager.TilesArray.Add (Tile);
    GameManager.AllTilesPoints.Add (gridPos);
}
}
```

GameManager

Теперь при создании тайлов мы можем обращаться к их скрипту и ставить им нужные позиции:

```
public static List<GameObject> TilesArray = new List<GameObject>();
public static List<Point> AllTilesPoints = new List<Point>();
[SerializeField]
private GameObject TilePrefab;
private float TileWidthOffset; //...переменная для рассчёта ширины тайла
private float TileHeightOffset;//...переменная для рассчёта высоты тайла

void Start(){
    SetTileOffsets();
    CreateTiles (TilePrefab);
}

private void CreateTiles(GameObject TilePrefab){
    Vector3 TilesStart = new Vector3 (0f,0f,0f); //С какой позиции мы будем начинать спавнить тайлы
    //Здесь возможен любой другой цикл for создания тайлов, это уже на усмотрения твоей задумки, сколько и как нужны расположить тайлы
    //Пример создания сетки из пяти тайлов
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            GameObject Tile = Instantiate (TilePrefab);
            Vector3 newTilePos = new Vector3(TilesStart.x + (TileWidthOffset * x), TilesStart.y+ (TileHeightOffset * y), 0f);
            Tile.GetComponent<TileScript> ().SetTileGridPosition (new Point (x, y), Tile, newTilePos );
        }
    }
}

private void SetTileOffsets(){
    //....Здесь твой метод, рассчитывающий высоту / ширину твоего тайла для тайл оффсета....

}
private void GoOverTilesArray(Point TileCheckPoint){
    for (int i = 0; i < TilesArray.Count; i++) {
        if (TileCheckPoint = TilesArray [i].GetComponent<TileScript> ().GridPosition) {
            Debug.Log ("Это тайл с позицией: " + TileCheckPoint.X + ", " + TileCheckPoint.Y);
        }

    }
}
```

Как-то так. В дальнейшем мы можем создать метод проверки, например, добавив в скрипт игрока событие на OnMouseDown():

```
private void OnMouseDown(){
    CheckTilesDirections ();
}

private void CheckTilesDirections(){
    //Метод проверки направления тайла
    Point PlayerPoint = Player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().GridPosition;
    float x = PlayerPoint.X;
    float y = PlayerPoint.Y;
    Point TileCheckPoint = new Point (x, y);
    //Проверяем существование пойнта в листе и если он существует, то какой это тайл
    //Допустим мы проверяем квадрат позиций вокруг игрока
    for (y + 1; y >= (y - 1); y--) {
        for (x - 1; x <= (x + 1); x++) {
            TileCheckPoint = new Point (x, y);
            if (GameManager.AllTilesPoints.Contains (TileCheckPoint)) {
                GameManager.GoOverTilesArray (TileCheckPoint); //Здесь мы просто выводим позиции тайлов в квадрате позиций, окружающих игрока.
                //Таким образом, пройдясь через массив тайлов и сопоставив их пойнт позиции в сетке с нужной нам для проверки позицией, 
                //мы выводим в консль информацию о позиции этого тайла. Дальше уже додумать код для проверки тайла справа и спереди игрока,
                //я думаю не составит труда. Подкину мысль: if ((TileCheckPoint.X= PlayerPoint.X) && (TileCheckPoint.Y=PlayerPoint.Y+1)) - тайл слева в твоём случае
                //if ((TileCheckPoint.X = PlayerPoint.X+1) && (TileCheckPoint.Y = PlayerPoint.Y)) - тайл впереди игрока

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Конечно, здесь всё специфично, и подобрать вариант для работы с твоей задумкой можно по аналогии. Какое-то слишком подробное описание получилось, вплоть до методов инстанциирования с конкретными позициями, ну-с, дальше уже тебе решать как эту информацию применить.
UPD: Point.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public struct Point 
{
    public int X {get; set;}
    public int Y {get; set;}

public Point(int x, int y){
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;

}


}
```

Comment: можете в виде кода показать?

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас подредактирую ответ

Comment: почему `Point` подсвечивается красным ?

Comment: `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Point' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`
`

Comment: У тебя нет Point скрипта, конечно же, я просто подумал, он у тебя уже предусмотрен

Comment: Апдейтнул ответ, создай Point скрипт с этим кодом

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74701/discussion-between-fan4i-and-kill-noise).